# Using SQLite with dot42

Tags: dot42

Is it possible to use ADO.NET to access SQLite Databases on android using dot42? I know there are C# wrappers for the underlying library:

[SQLite.NET](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, not at the momenet. To use Sqlite-NET ORM, dot42 is missing System.Linq.Expressions namespace. Maybe would be feasible to use some JAVA/Sqlite ORM and call it form c#, but haven't tried it yet. Dot42 is going to upload base class library to github under Apache license, so maybe missing parts will be completed with the help of community.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think there is a lot of potential in their product.

Comment: https://github.com/dot42/api

Comment: See answer in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867847/asynchronous-sqlite-sample-with-dot42